# Cos'è un "ulivo di fosso"?

Tags: meaning

Nel racconto *Casa d'altri* di Silvio D'Arzo ho letto:

> Aveva pelle scura e rugosa, e capelli color grigio-passera e vene dure e sporgenti come neanche un uomo le ha. E se una pianta può in qualche modo servire a dar l’idea di un cristiano, bene, un vecchio **ulivo di fosso** è quel che ci vuole per lei.

Ho letto la definizione di "fosso" in parecchi dizionari. Tuttavia non capisco cos'è un "ulivo di fosso". Sapreste spiegarmelo?

Comment: Si tratterà di un ulivo cresciuto in riva ad un fosso, probabilmente sta a indicare il fatto che è cresciuto selvatico e non curato. Mi immagino un'analogia tra la persona descritta ed un vecchio albero selvatico e nodoso.

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi Penso che tu possa espandere il tuo commento in una risposta

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: Sono d'accordo con Denis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non mi pare esista una definizione esatta di "*ulivo di fosso*"; ritengo che l'autore abbia aggiunto "di fosso" per specificare il fatto che si tratta di un albero di ulivo cresciuto in riva ad un fosso, e probabilmente sta a indicare il fatto che è cresciuto selvatico e non curato. Il brano riportato utilizza questa immagine come analogia tra la persona descritta ed un vecchio albero selvatico e nodoso.